# audio is not clearly working in android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, audio-streaming

I tried to play audio file from raw folder based on the user selection but if user select or changing two or more files, then audio is not working properly but it streams selected files and also previously selected files after changing the option. I'm new to android...I have posted my code below, anyone help me out with this..

```
switch (Global.id)
{
case R.id.radioButton1:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.kalimba);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;

case R.id.radioButton2:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.maid);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;

case R.id.radioButton3:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sleep_away);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
}
```

and here is a **onDestroy** method.

```
private void destroy()
{
mMediaPlayer.release();
mMediaPlayer.reset();
mMediaPlayer.stop();            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

```
if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
{
     mMediaPlayer.reset();
     mMediaPlayer.stop();

}
```

Add above condition in Switch case

```
switch (Global.id)
{
case R.id.radioButton1:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.kalimba);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
case R.id.radioButton2:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.maid);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
case R.id.radioButton3:
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sleep_away);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
}
```

Comment: @Somasundaram ok, I am waiting then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your player. Do something like this:

```
//global
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

//switch statement somewhere else
switch (Global.id)
{
case R.id.radioButton1:
    otherSong(R.raw.kalimba);
    break;

case R.id.radioButton2:
    otherSong(R.raw.maid);
    break;

case R.id.radioButton3:
    otherSong(R.raw.sleep_away);
    break;
}

//method for changing song
private void otherSong(int song) {
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {          
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(song);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
{
     mMediaPlayer.reset();
   //  mMediaPlayer.stop(); // reset its more than enought here im afraid you migth end up here whith      illegal exception when you call stop right after reset without creating a new media 

}
```

reminder: calling reset() will put the media player to its idle state so no need to call stop

Edit: so it should be something like that

```
switch (Global.id)
{
case R.id.radioButton1:
      if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
       // mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.kalimba);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);


    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
case R.id.radioButton2:
       if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
       // mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.maid);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
case R.id.radioButton3:
    if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() )  // Checking if already playing any song
    {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
       // mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sleep_away);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    break;
}
```

No need to call prepare at least in my experience i got some crash after calling prepare
Edit: i advise you to check if its playing before creating mMediaPlayer.